# Is there a way to specify as width of a contained div the full width of the scrollable area of the parent?

Tags: html, css

I found that if I put an `overflow-auto` div that contains other divs the width of those sub-divs is just the width of the visible part of the parent and not the width of the scrollable area.

[image: example of the problem]

You can see an example at http://jsfiddle.net/UdgCE/

Is there a way to specify as width the full width of the scrollable area instead?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is ideal and it probably doesn't quite answer or match what you are intending to do.

However it appears as though the containers inside of the scrollable container exhibit similar behavior comparable to how a container would stretch a window. For example if you had a div with `height:100%;` and `width:100%;` it would stretch the view port and nothing more.

With that in mind, after messing around for a while, the only pure CSS solution I have found is to set specific "matching" pixel values to your inner / outer  containers.

An example here ... http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/UdgCE/27/

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="overflow:auto" id="container"> 
      <div id="inner-wrap">        
          <div  style="white-space:pre" id="content">
             This is a the text of the first div and it's veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long
          </div>
        </div>
      <div style="background-color:#FFFF00" id="yellow">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#yellow {
  width:2000px;    
}

#container {
 border:1px solid red;
    width:400px;
}
#content { 
    width:2000px;    
    border:1px solid #333;
}

#inner-wrap {
 width:2000px;   
}
​
```

This hardly seems ideal but it seems to work. I am guessing you will most likely have to use javaScript to measure the width of the scrollable container and then match the inner divs to that dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "clearfix" to the wrapper div fixed it for me.
This makes the wrapping div expand to the width of the text. Not just overflowing.

http://jsfiddle.net/7a67j/